# absolute positioning inside a table

Tags: html, css, positioning

I need to position something with absolute positioning inside a td. To get around the fact that a td is undefined when setting it to relative, I use a div set to relative inside my td then inside that div I have an inner div set to absolute. This all works great when I have content filling up the td. When I set the content of the td to display none then the absolute positioning gets all screwed up.

Does anyone know why this would be.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="relative">
                <div class='absolute'>
                    <p>A</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot"></div>
            <div class="slot"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="relative">
             <div class='absolute'>
               <p>B</p>
           </div>
           </div>
           <div class="slot hidden"></div>
           <div class="slot"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
td{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100px;
    height:60px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.slot{
  width:100px;
  height:29px;
  background-color:#999;
  border:1px dashed blue;
}

.relative{
    position:relative;
}

.absolute{
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

And a live version: http://jsfiddle.net/HgEtQ/

In the fiddle above you can see the first table cell works correctly. The absolutely positioned div is in the correct space. The second one has hidden the top slot and now the absolute positioning is not in the top left corner anymore. If you take out both slots then it really screws up the absolute positioning. I need to positioning it absolute because some of the elements will be shifted depending on the element.

Comment: perhaps you can add an "&nbsp;" to an empty td?

Comment: show some code, its hard to convert your words to html and css

Comment: Ok just updated above with a jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here.

You have this:

```
td {
    /*...*/
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

That will push the content of the cells to the bottom.

Also, an absolutely positioned element is [removed from the normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning) so it won't contribute to its parent's height:

> It is removed from the normal flow entirely (it has no impact on later siblings). An absolutely positioned box establishes a new containing block for normal flow children and absolutely (but not fixed) positioned descendants.

In particular, this means that your `div.relative` elements have a height of zero but they will still have an upper left corner so your absolute positioning offsets are anchored somewhere.

Then you have `<div class="slot hidden">` and the `hidden` removes the `<div>` from the layout so you effectively have just this:

```
<div class="relative"></div> <!-- Height zero -->
<div class="slot"></div>     <!-- Height 29px -->
```

That combined with the `vertical-align: bottom` means that your second `div.absolute` will be positioned 5px from the top of the `div.slot` and that is 25px from the bottom of the table cell.

The first cell works fine because the two visible `div.slot` elements push the `div.relative` right to the top of the cell, then the `div.absolute` is positioned 5px from the top of the `div.relative` and that is 5px from the top of the table cell.

Unfortunately, adding `position: relative` to a `<td>` is a bit dodgy as far as browsers go so you'll need some hackery to get your positioning right while keeping `vertical-align: bottom`. You could re-structure the `<td>`s like this:

```
<td>
    <div class="relative">
        <div class='absolute'>
            <p>A</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nonsense">
        <div class="slot"></div>
        <div class="slot"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

And the CSS like this:

```
td{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100px;
    height:60px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.slot{
    width:100px;
    height:29px;
    background-color:#999;
    border:1px dashed blue;
}

.relative {
    position:relative;
}
.nonsense {
    height: 62px; /* td[height] + 2 for the borders */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.absolute{
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/aV4nT/

Or you could use [`visibility: hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-visibility):

> **hidden**
>   The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout. Furthermore, descendants of the element will be visible if they have 'visibility: visible'.

instead of `display: none` for your `.hidden` class:

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This will leave both `div.slot` elements taking up space and affecting the layout but only the second one will be seen.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RcdNh/

Comment: What a great answer. I really appreciate your time explaining the answer also. Not often do people explain the problem, they just give you a magical fix and say, it works because it does. Thank you, thank you :)

Comment: @Chapsterj: Thanks. I need the explanation and research to convince myself that I know what's wrong and that I'm actually fixing something (rather just blindly kludging around the problem by adding another uglier problem); seems like a waste not to share the explanation once I have it :)