# Looking for an JQuery to check for image visibility. The image control is inside a repeater control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

What is the eqivalent JQuery for the below?

```
function ChooseProd(obj) {

        var objectID = document.getElementById(obj.id);
        var isVisible = objectID.style.visibility;
        if (isVisible == "visible") alert("Image visible");
        else alert("Not visible");
        return false;
        }
```

I tried with

```
var isVisible = $(obj.id).is(":visible");
if (isVisible == "visible") alert("Image visible");
else alert("Not visible");
```

But not working

**Edit:**

ItemDataBound event is as under

```
protected void repTest_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            LinkButton lnkBtn = e.Item.FindControl("lnkProdName") as LinkButton;
            Image img = e.Item.FindControl("prodImg") as Image;
            img.Attributes.Add("style", "visibility:hidden");

            if (lnkBtn != null)
            {
                var tt = lbl.ClientID;
                lnkBtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return ChooseProd(" + img.ClientID + ");");
            }
        }
    }
```

And the Javascript is as under

```
function ChooseProd(obj) 
{        

 var isVisible = $('#' + obj.id).is(":visible");
 if (isVisible) alert("Image visible"); 
 else alert("Not visible");            
 return false;           

}
```

**But irrespective of visibility:hidden or visible, the isVisible  is coming as true.**

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think your jQuery selector is wrong, change this:

```
var isVisible = $(obj.id).is(":visible");
```

to this:

```
var isVisible = $('#' + obj.id).is(":visible");
```

The jQuery function, `$()`, takes a CSS-ish selector, not a raw ID.

Also, [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is) returns a boolean, not a string, so you want just `if(isVisible)`.

Comment: But not getting the expected result . The outer text is <IMG id=repTest_ctl00_prodImg style="BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; VISIBILITY: hidden; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px" alt="" src="D:\Image\1.jpg">

Comment: It looks like you're passing the clientId to the ChooseProd function. If that is the image tag id, then you don't need obj.id, just $('#' + obj) should suffice.

Comment: it won't work. according to jquery documentation, "Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout." OP has set `visibility:hidden`

Comment: But in that case the selector is #[object] while if i do $('#' + obj.id) the selector is #repTest_ctl00_prodImg.. but in none of the way i am able to get the result... am i missing something?

Comment: @mcUser: have you checked my answer?

Comment: And naveen, then what changes i need to do for executing the same?

Answer (score 1):

`is()` returns true or false. change your if statement to `if (isVisible)`

Comment: Also, `$(obj.id)` should be `$('#' + obj.id)`.

Comment: But +1 for spotting the boolean problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `.is(":visible")` selector won't work in your code because, you are setting `visibility:hidden`. According to jQuery documentation on [`.is(":visible")`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

> Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered to be visible, 
>   since they still consume space in the layout. During animations that hide an element, the
>   element is considered to be visible until the end of the animation. During animations to 
>   show an element, the element is considered to be visible at the start at the animation.

---

Working code snippet in jQuery

```
function ChooseProd(objID) {
    var $obj = $("#" + objID);
    var isVisible = $obj.css('visibility') != 'hidden';
    var isDisplayed = $obj.is(':visible');
    var alertText = (isVisible && isDisplayed) ? "Visible element" : "Hidden Element";
    alert(alertText);        
    return false;
}
```

---

Its better to set `display: none` which would save the code from checking the *visibility* property.
So, why don't you try using `display:none` instead?

In short, you code will work, if you change <strike>`img.Attributes.Add("style", "visibility:hidden");`</strike> to `img.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");` inside your `repTest_ItemDataBound`

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/9zGXz/

Another comprehensive demo(forked from @mu is too short): http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/dM6yR/

Comment: There are times when you want to use [`visibility`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/visibility) but there [are pretty rare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798532/absolute-positioning-inside-a-table/6798889#6798889). But you are right about `:visible`.

Comment: there was a typo fixed by @mu is too short. try now

Comment: yes. but why? i am noit able to get that. the javascript was pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

please try to put # before obj.id

i think this will work